# Querying arrays in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am doing a transformation on a table (renaming columns, etc). TEST table looks like below:
[image]

So when I run this query it returns the correct result:

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
       r3.material AS item_material,
       r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3
FROM TEST
```

Now I want to have r2 and r4 columns as well so I do the below query:
Solution 1

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
           r3.material AS item_material,
           r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3,
       STRUCT(
           r2.itemId AS item_id
       ) AS r2
FROM TEST
```

It gives me this error:

```
Cannot access field itemId on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<itemId INT64>> at [11:12]
```

So I tried solution 2 as below:

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
           r3.material AS item_material,
           r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3,
       STRUCT(
           (SELECT r2s.itemId FROM UNNEST(r2) r2s) AS item_id
       ) AS r2
FROM TEST
```

Which gives me r2 perfectly but when I add r4 to the query :

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
           r3.material AS item_material,
           r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3,
       STRUCT(
           (SELECT r2s.itemId FROM UNNEST(r2) r2s) AS item_id
       ) AS r2,
       STRUCT(
           (SELECT r4s.itemCategory FROM UNNEST(r4) r2s) AS item_category
       ) AS r4
FROM TEST
```

it gives below error:

```
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

So I moved to solution 3:

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
           r3.material AS item_material,
           r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3,
       r2.itemId AS item_id,
       r4.itemCategory AS item_category
FROM TEST,
UNNEST(r2) AS r2,
UNNEST(r4) AS r4
```

Again if I add just r2 it gives me correct results but when I add r4 to the above query it returns an empty table as a result!

Eventually I created solution 4 which gives me what I want but there are lots of unnecessary left join added and made it really complex query. Could you please help me to avoid so many left joins?

```
SELECT r1,
       STRUCT(
           r3.material AS item_material,
           r3.weight AS item_weight
       ) AS r3,
       r2.itemId AS item_id,
       r4.itemCategory AS item_category
FROM TEST,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(r2) AS r2,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(r4) AS r4
```